# How to make my to menu screen size independent in CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

For a top menu of my website I am using a css file. The menu works fine for me but I noticed that on smaller screen the menu breaks down, that two or more item of the menu coming down for lack of space. I tried to modified the different parameter of the css but still it did not work. Can anyone please suggest me for the modification of the following css so that the menu works same in different resolution of devices.

CSS

```
body {
 margin:0px;
}
#nav { 
    background-color:#262626; 
    width:100%; 
    height:50px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px #5E5E5E; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px;
}

#nav > ul {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0;} 
#nav > ul > li {list-style:inside none; padding:5px; margin:0; float:left; display:block; position:relative;} 
#nav > ul > li > a{ padding: 10px;  outline:none; display:block; position:relative; padding:12px 20px; font: 1em/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); } 

#nav > ul > li > a:after{ content:''; position:absolute;  top:-1px; bottom:-1px; right:-2px; z-index:99; } 
#nav ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after{top:0; bottom:0;} 
#nav > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{ content:''; position:absolute; top:18px; right:6px; border:5px solid transparent; border-top:5px solid #fff; } 
#nav > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:19px;} 
#nav ul li.has-sub:hover > a{ background:#2198bf; border-color:#3f3f3f; padding-bottom:13px; padding-top:13px; top:-1px; z-index:999; } 
#nav ul li.has-sub:hover > ul, #cssmenu_top ul li.has-sub:hover > div{display:block;} 
#nav ul li.has-sub > a:hover{background:#2198bf; border-color:#3f3f3f;} 
#nav ul li > ul, #cssmenu_top ul li > div{ display:none; width:auto; position:absolute; top:38px; padding:10px 0; background:#3f3f3f; border-radius:0 0 5px 5px; z-index:999; } 
#nav ul li > ul{width:200px;} 
#nav ul li > ul li{display:block; list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; position:relative;} 
#nav ul li > ul li a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; margin:0; padding:8px 20px; font:10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); } 

















.title { 
    color:#FF0000; 
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-family:verdana; 
    font-size:20px; 
    width:20px; 
    margin-top:6px; 
    margin-left:150px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    float:left;
}
.subtitle { 
    color:#FF0000; 
    font-family:verdana; 
    font-size:15px;
}
#navigation{ 
    list-style-type:none; 
}
li { 
    display:inline; 
    padding:10px;
}
#nav a{ 
    font-family:verdana; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#EDEDED;
} 
#nav a:hover { 
    color:#BDBDBD;
}
#body { 
    width:98%; 
    margin:0px auto; 
    margin-top:80px; 
    font-family:verdana;


}
hr {
    border:1px solid #262626;
}


.menu_extended{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #CC0000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px #5E5E5E; 
}
```

In the body of my html page i am writting the following way for creation of menu:

```
<div id="nav">
        <p class="title">
            <a href="#"><span style="color:0000FF;"> </span></a>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="read_home.php">Reading</a></li>
            <li><a href="multimedia.php">Multimedia</a></li>
            <li><a href="test_home.php" >Test Yourself</a></li>
            <li><a href="sit_for_exam.php" style="background-color:#CC0000;font-size:19px;color:#FFFFFF;border-radius:0px;">Sit for Exam</a></li>
            <li><a href="test_analysis_home.php">Analysis</a></li>
            <li><a href="tips.php">Tips And Tricks</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Reponsive menu bar can easily be achieved by media queries.If you don't about them then seach it on google.I am providing you a demo url https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries. 
In this you have to apply css to your menu bar according to width of device

Answer (score 0):

To make a Responsive menu bar and to target each devices. you can use [@media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/).

```
// normal style
#header-image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:url('image.gif');
}

// show a larger image when you're on a big screen
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #header-image {
        background-image:url('large-image.gif');
    }
}

// remove header image when printing.
@media print {
    #header-image {
        display: none;
    }
}
```